# file-roller's "Extract Here" unpacks content directly to target folder instead of creating a directory named like the archive

Tags: nautilus, file-roller

I am using the default Ubuntu 'Extract Here' context menu command for .zip files. Inside the archive is a single folder 'scans' with some arbitrary files inside.

When I use 'Extract Here', it creates a folder with the same name as the archive, and begins extracting. When it is finished extracting, however, it names the folder 'scans'.

How can I make the default right click extraction create a folder with the same name as the archive, and put the contents of the archive in there? It seems like this should be a fairly standard thing, but the default extraction tool doesn't have this. Yes, I can do it in the terminal, and yes I can probably write a nautilus script to do it or whatever, but is there just a very basic way to have my archives not extract to 'scans'... because they all end up having the same name.

This is something I do every day, and it is becoming tiresome to have to manually rename the folder to something unique.

Comment: If in the end it extracts the contained folder 'scans' and 'scans' is what shows up, what is the problem exactly? Are you complaining about what happens *during* the extraction (and yes it does that regardless of the zip or rar contents)? I would say we have way more important things to be concerned about.

Comment: No. I wanted it to extract the contents of the archive to a folder with the same name as the archive... Anyway I fixed it using nautilus-actions.

Comment: The default behavior is extracting the contents "as is", always. It makes no sense otherwise except in very specific situations. Why we would change something that works and it's only logical just to cater to the particular needs of an insignificant minority? And just because that's the horrible Windows default that you're used to?

Comment: It is not a horrible Windows default. It makes perfect sense to extract to folder named after the archive. Often archives are coming with multiple files. When they are located @user589808 somewhere like desktop, all those files crowd the space and can be tedious to organize again. Maybe you are the insignificant minority, who needs to change your habits. Current behavour of file-roller is horrible in my opinion, like many other things about it.

Comment: The issue was (from what I recall, I'm on Centos7 now) that it actually WOULD extract to a folder - but only if there was more than one file (or directory) in the archive. So the behavior was inconsistent, depending on the contents of the archive. Now with Centos7, I have a huge QOL issue that has not been fixed in over a YEAR: https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=15657

Comment: It seems the *nix community really struggles with extracting archives efficiently